# pop-up maps in CICS

Tags: popup, cics

In my project I have to display a map, and when user presses f5 i have to display a pop-up map
and the contents of the main map should appear as protected. Then when the user presses f3 
the pop-up should disappear and the contents of the main map should become unprotected. I did this by moving DFHBMPRO to map attributes for making them protected and stored all the values entered by user in commarea so that the values are retained when the user presses f3 and comes back to main map. It worked. The problem is I have 24 fields in the map, to all of them I have to move DFHBMPRO, and all 24 values should be moved to commarea also. Can any one suggest a simple way to do this.

Comment: I don't know how to create a pop-up in cics. Can u suggest me a book or a link for that. I am a beginner in mainframes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Store the entire main map in your commarea, attributes, lengths and all, the whole copybook generated when you compile your mapset.  Use a single group move to copy it to and from the commarea.

I've always gone through the tedious effort of coding the individual MOVE statements, but now that I think about it the above should work just fine.

I'll be interested if anyone chimes in with a better idea.